# Add column for another table with condition - Power BI - DAX - Power Query

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have a table with DATE, ACCOUNT, and RESULTS. Additionally, there is a second table with ACCOUNT, START DATE, COMPANY, and PERCENTAGE. I need to incorporate the percentage information from the second table into the first table.

Table1:

[image]

Table2:

[image]

However, the percentage changes over time due to new START DATE entries. Is there a way to bring in the PERCENTAGE column using date ranges or approximate dates?

Comment: You did not include company in Table1.  How can you decide which percent to bring in from Table2?

Answer (score 0):

If you are always using the beginning of the year you could add a custom column

```
Date.StartOfYear([DATE])
```

and then merge using ACCOUNT and STARTOFYEAR column.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked:

```
COLUMN = maxx(FILTER(ALL(Table2), Table1[ACCOUNT] = Table2[ACCOUNT] && 'Table2'[DATESTART].[Date]<Table1[DATE]),[DATESTART].[Date])
```